# How to include angular 5 libary without using npm install

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-library

In `angular 5` , install package or lib required npm install. I'd like to know 
if it is possible to include library like this :

`<script src="http://xxxx/.js" ><script>`

or use `angular-cli`

[image][image]

I don't know which file i should put in the new project .Or how to use it
for example :

In angularjs 1.x
we could use the script xxx for us to include 3rd party lib, i'd like to do is the same doing the 3rd party lib without using npm install.That's all.It better 
using below example

````

```

Comment: what is the exact issue please rephrase your question

Comment: let me update my question sorry.

Comment: I'm interested to know why you don't want to use npm install (even for 3rd party libs)

Comment: Have a look at [unpkg](https://unpkg.com)

Comment: because some of our lib need to be use internal site.

Comment: @JosephMTsai not sure what that means exactly, but the fact that you have some internal lib doesn't prevent the usage of npm.

Comment: @JBNizet ,yes for some reason we can't use npm to publish our libary

Comment: Then don't publish it. Or publish it in a private npm repository. Or use a private git repo and install your library from a git url. Again, the fact that you have some internal lib doesn't prevent the usage of npm. You need to learn it, though, like everything else.

Comment: @JBNizet so how do i use in url again. could you provide some sample thanks

Comment: *how do i use in url again*: I don't know what that means.

Comment: using without the npm just include js file

Comment: We're turning in circle here. Forget that idea. Use the Angular CLI, and learn how to integrate your library into the npm ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

For the script to be available via npm mechanism, you can simply replace it with git url instead of the package name, e.g. git@bitbucket.com:name/package.

From [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies):

```
<protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish> | #semver:<semver>]
```

Alternatively, you can use a combination of npm link, but you're restricted to asingle system.

Finally, Typescript itself can help you. Say you have your app in `src/app` folder and your lib in `src/lib`. You can simply use regular typescript (or ES) import to import the lib in your code. Angular should tkae care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with `paths` in `tsconfig.json` file with a library and an application as part of the same Angular workspace (the same `node_modules` folder). But for me it's not working when I have it in different projects (Angular workspaces), probably because of different versions of Angular dependencies. `ng serve` says:
`error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'`

**Update**

Finally realized it! It's possible to use `npm link` to create symlink to a library, and inside `angular.json` file to set property `preserveSymlinks` to `true`. Example:

`"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      ...
      "preserveSymlinks": true,
      ...`